# Error after updating to Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 14.04

I have a dual boot laptop, Windows and Ubuntu. I was updating my Ubuntu from 14.04 to 15.10. After updating I started Ubuntu and the whole GUI has gone for a toss. No program can be run. A startup error occurs saying unable to detect graphics environment when i am trying to run any program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

1. Go to terminal CTRL+ALT+F1
2. Login to the terminal
3. Make sure you have network connection
4. Run sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop unity
5. Select Y, and the downloading starts (this may take one hour)
6. After it finishes installing, sudo service lightdm restart
7. GUI should appear on screen.